# Check for table lock in conditional statement

Tags: mysql, information-schema, locking

How can I make this work?

```
IF( EXISTS (SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE In_use < 2 and `Database` like 'MYDB' ) ) THEN
 -- DO SOMETHING
END IF
```

### Context

I want to run some sql statements inside a procedure, only if the table `x` is not locked ( because of updates or any other reason ).

I want to do this on the MySQL server side as I have clients that trigger this procedure from more than 12 machines from bash, c and  c#.

So is there any way to get the table lock information in a conditional statement on the server side ?

Comment: what if using within shell.. if [ `mysql -uroot -pmysql -P3308 --protocol=TCP -e "show open tables where In_use =0" |wc -l` -gt 0 ];then echo "hi";else echo "bye";fi..hope it helps

Comment: That would work, but I need to use it in a stored procedure, as I have clients connecting from all kind of platforms.

Comment: This seems like potentially a bit of [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?  You can't do it directly, of course, but depending on the motivation, there might be a viable alternative.  Also, what version of MySQL Server?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sql server is 5.5, but if that's a problem I can upgrade it. Added more info to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to this seems like it would be to use a named lock.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

```
IF GET_LOCK('my_arbitrary_lock_name',0) THEN 
  ...
  DO RELEASE_LOCK('my_arbitrary_lock_name');
ELSE
  ...
END IF;
```

This pool of locks is independent of table locks, metadata locks, row locks, or any other kind of "actual" database object locks, and obtaining, releasing, or checking these locks is also independent of transactions.

The only thing that's actually getting "locked" here is the name you passed as the first argument, which is an arbitrary string.  All this does is ensure that no more than one thread can hold a lock of the same name at the same time.  The others have to wait for up to the number of seconds specified in the 2nd argument to `GET_LOCK()` otherwise they don't get the lock (and `GET_LOCK()` returns false).  After the timeout (which is 0, in the example, to wait no time at all) if the lock isn't free, the function returns false; if the lock is free then the lock is obtained by that connection and the function returns true.  Other connections can discover which connection holds a lock with the `IS_USED_LOCK()` function, but they can't interfere (other than kill the connection, given sufficient privileges).

If you "forget" to release a lock, it's automatically released if you disconnect.

Asking for a different lock will also release the current lock you hold in MySQL, and asking for a lock you hold will release it and then try to re-obtain it, potentially handing it over to another thread.  These behaviors vary between MySQL and some versions of MariaDB, it's best to be explicit when using them rather than relying on such side-effects for intentional behavior.

Comment: Nice. Something I didn't know. And congrats for reaching 10K :)

Comment: @ypercube thanks. And thanks, again. :)  Among other things, I find this very useful with recurring jobs in the event scheduler.  If another thread holds my lock I know the previous run of the event is still going, so I shouldn't proceed.  I use a simple wrapper procedure that I call `get_lock_or_die()` that returns if the lock is yours, or throws a fatal error with `SIGNAL SQLSTATE 45000 ...` otherwise.  Errors thrown inside scheduled events go to the MySQL error log, so as a side effect, I get a log entry to let me know the previous execution of the scheduled event ran longer than it should.

Comment: Nice, it will probably be what I'll be going for, though I would have liked to do stuff based on something equivalent to `In_use` from the `SHOW OPEN TABLES`, as it doesn't require any tampering with any other procedures that use the table.

Comment: @clickstefan there are some other possibilities, like the [`innodb_trx` table in `information_schema`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-trx-table.html) or even the `processlist` table that could potentially give you programmatically accessible and useful information when deciding to proceed, but you don't want to be overly aggressive in querying them because some `information_schema` queries can be relatively resource-intensive.

Comment: So why isn't `show open table` accessible programmatically ?

Comment: @clickstefan I don't know why they designed some of the `SHOW` statements the way they did and didn't put the same things in `information_schema`.  If you or someone you know is proficient in C, it's actually possible to create a [custom storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pluggable-storage.html) in MySQL that could expose this information via an SQL interface, as a queryable table.  I've contemplated writing one for `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` but haven't gotten around to it (and you can discover some attributes about the slave status from `information_schema`.`processlist`).